# Angular way to open and close panels

Tags: angularjs, tabs, panels

In Angular if I had a few panels, similar to tabs how do you open the panel on click and animate it up, if I click a different panel new html is loaded in, but if I click an open panel it needs to animate down.

Almost exactly like http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview however 3 of them.

I've looked at both ngRouter and UI-Router, I think UI-Router is closer to what I need because you can remove a view.

Comment: Almost exactly like this, but in Angular http://jsfiddle.net/aUHwA/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CskOQFgtHnTbEqVH1fdl?p=preview) to show something similar, but you'll have to tweak the CSS transitions.

This is using `ngAnimate` and CSS transitions to control the animations.

Markup:

```
<div class="tab-area" ng-switch on="activeTab">
  <div class="tab tab1" ng-switch-when="1">
    <h1>tab 1 content</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tab2" ng-switch-when="2">
    <h1>tab 2 content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li ng-click="setTab(1)">tab 1</li>
  <li ng-click="setTab(2)">tab 2</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.activeTab = 0;
$scope.setTab = function(tabId){
  $scope.activeTab = $scope.activeTab===tabId ? 0 : tabId;
};
```

Comment: It's obviously a matter of opinion but, while I think this is a great simple example of how to solve this problem, you will quickly run into much more complicated scenarios, wishing you were using ui-router from the start.

Answer (score 0):

[angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) is definitely what you want, you can see that their sample [site](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/) is almost a complete recreation of your posted jQuery example.

Comment: What would be the way to do a logic check similar to 
if (thisPanel == 'open') { thisPanel.close(); } else { openPanel() }

Comment: If you use angular-ui then you need to think more about it in a stateful manner. Their example site is very good at demonstrating this.. it's not "if (thisPanel == 'open')" rather than "if the activeState is 'contacts' then do x". You can use the state transition hooks to execute code at certain times as well (onEnter, onExit, etc).

Comment: I will look into this I guess you can't use the default ui-sref="contact" if you are applying logic based on state? That's where the examples are lacking for me, on the site.

Comment: yeah, you definitely can. The demo site shows how you can use the current state to conditionally change items on the page (should the tab look depressed, for instance). It depends on how far you want to go with your logic though, that would require a more thorough question I think